# How to get available font weights?

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-face, typeface

Is there any way to get list of weights for particular font in JavaScript?

I want to build selector like in Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can extract that info from the users's computer. @font-face fonts can have this info passed in. In any case this should help you out: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness

Comment: You mean do you want the width of the font ...??

Comment: I mean I need to get a list of available font styles in general.

Comment: There is no such font styles in JS ... See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontweight.asp

Comment: :) yes, I know. That is why I asking how to make similar control. How to figure out that e.g. 300 and 400 for particular font is the same.

Comment: So that you want to measure the width of the font ...??

Comment: @PlasticRabbit It's a crazy idea but you can render fonts with different font-weight on canvas then save them to base64 and compare results. In theory if rendered fonts has no differences they base64 will be equal.

Comment: Somewhat related, Remy Sharp has tried to detect Comic Sans with JS [How to detect if a font is installed](http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/)

Comment: and there's another attempt here [JS/CSS Font Detector](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm unclear about your end goal, however....

If you are using something like google fonts you should already know all the possible weights available. In other words if you supply your own font then you are the master of all that is available.

Answer (score 2):

Nope! Whether one typeface is actually a font-weight of another is esoteric knowledge that Javascript has no way of working out. You can *define* what font-weights a font-family has using CSS `@font-face` rules, and in a way this kind of illustrates the impossibility of achieving what you're asking.

Immediately below, I've got a pretty standard `@font-face` setup for a font with 3 weights.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Barney;
  src: url(barney_regular.ttf);
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Barney;
  src: url(barney_light.ttf);
  font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Barney;
  src: url(barney_bold.ttf);
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

But knowing that each of those `.ttf` files represents a different weight of the same font family is arbitrary. Here I've specified it, because I'm aware of it. If an automated service, eg Font Squirrel, had taken those 3 files, it would probably have come out with this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: barney_regular;
  src: url(barney_regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: barney_light;
  src: url(barney_light.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: barney_bold;
  src: url(barney_bold.ttf);
}
```

Here, these 3 weights have actually all been specified as distinct font families, which is obviously a mistake. But in theory I could do stupider stuff:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: barney;
  src: url(barney_regular.ttf);
  font-weight: 500;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: barney;
  src: url(barney_regular.ttf);
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: barney;
  src: url(barney_regular.ttf);
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Above, the same exact typeface is being assigned to 3 different weights. So even if Javascript could detect the relationships within `@font-face` declarations, like what file is associated with what weight, style & family; how many weights have been specified… It still couldn't tell you whether those resources exist, have been downloaded, accurately represent a different width of the same font.

Web typography has undergone big changes over the past 10 years, but it's still (relatively speaking) a rubbish medium for type-setting.

Comment: Downvoter: are you saying my answer isn't correct? Care to validate the assertion, ask for clarification?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [CSS Font Loading API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API)
The font must be loaded into your document first, using css `@font-face` or  javascript [FontFace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace)
Here is a small example that lists the font weights for all loaded fonts:

```
document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
    const weights = {};
    for (const font of document.fonts.values()) {
        if (!weights.hasOwnProperty(font.family)) {
            weights[font.family] = [];
        }
        weights[font.family].push(font.weight);
    }
    console.log(weights);
});
```